# Where/How do I find the bonus content for the Destiny Digital Guardian Edition?

Tags: destiny

Everything seems pretty much stock. My inventory doesn't contain anything special either. Are the items level restricted? I completed the introduction portion and can't find anything extra at the tower vendors also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a definitive answer to this... The solution is to download the add-ons. The items are not unlocked in-game but rather as separate downloads. These downloads should be available without charge if you have purchased the package. If not, you may have to 'restore licenses' in your dashboard settings.

1. Destiny Collector's Edition Digital Content Pack
2. Vanguard Armory
3. Destiny Expansion Pass

You may need to close and re-open Destiny if you download these additions while the game is running.

Afterwards, you can claim the items themselves by visiting the the special orders kiosk and the Vanguard Armory by visiting the Tower.

**EDIT**

To locate the Vanguard Armory, visit the Quartermaster using the location in the map below.
[image: Vanguard Quartermaster Location]

You will have a selection of level 5 weapons and armor, each at a cost of 250 Glimmer.
[image: Vanguard Armory Items]

Comment: if you add the information of where the "vangaurd armory" is in game, this will easily be the most complete answer

Comment: Added armory info

Answer (score 6):

You are not the only one. At Bungie's forums, there are posts similar to this, and they say to have solved the problem. http://www.bungie.net/en/Forum/Post/68975633/0/0

"*If you are missing any content when you log into Destiny,
simply close the app,
go to your playstation (or xbox) settings,
restore licenses,
Go to Destiny - related content,
Download expansion pass and limited edition content,
Go back into Destiny,
Talk to Tess
...???...
PROFIT*"

If you still can't solve your problem, please contact Bungie at their [forums](http://www.bungie.net/en/Forum/Topics/0/0/0/%23Support) or [Twitter](https://twitter.com/BungieHelp).

Answer (score 1):

If as other answers have suggested you have sorted the download content / licensing issues then there should be some of the bonus content in the your mailbox at the city hub..

Answer (score 0):

All your pre order and special edition content is in the special orders vendor, in the oppisite end of the same building as the post master.

Answer (score 0):

To access your Vanguard Armory, see the Vanguard Quartermaster next to the Shipmaster in the tower. Also, your stuff can be found with Tess, the special orders kiosk next to the postmaster. Good luck!